# Finding what a series converges uniformly to.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

So, in my notes it says that the series

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2}) $

converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{2}log(x+1)$ on $[-a,a]$ for $0<a<1$ but that at $1$ it converges to $log2$

I think I've been able to prove to myself that it converges uniformly, but I have no idea how to show what it converges to exactly, and on different domains.

How might I approach this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}=\frac1{1-x^2}$$
$$\int f(x) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\frac12 \ln{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}=\frac1{1-x}$$
$$\frac12\int g(x) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2}=\frac12\ln {\frac{1}{1-x}}$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2}\right)=\frac12 \ln{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}-\frac12 \ln{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\frac12\ln(1+x)$$

---

For $x=1$,

$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k+2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{k}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{n+k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\frac1n}{1+\frac kn}$$
$$=\int_1^2\frac{dx}x=\left[\ln x\right]_1^2=\ln 2$$

Comment: That's much nicer than I expected! So is the $0<a<1$ due to the radius of convergence of this power series? How would we show $ln2$ is the limit at 1?

Comment: Thanks. At $x=1$, it becomes $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15+\cdots$ that is known to be $\ln 2$ (Taylor series). Well, the Taylor series convergence range is also $x<1$, but I think there's another way of proving it, I'll try it find it and get back to you.

Comment: @GregoryPeck I added the $x=1$ case above.

Comment: Brilliant! It makes so much more sense after you explained it. Hopefully I can follow a similar approach for other questions. Thanks a lot.